# Scan for surrounding WiFi devices and store MAC addresses in database in Python

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, wifi

The ultimate goal here is to be able to use a Raspberry Pi with a wireless adapter set to monitor mode, to scan all surrounding WiFi devices (even if they only have WiFi turned on and not associated), and keep a log of MAC addresses and timestamps in a local database (e.g. MySQL).

I have been using Python (specifically subprocess) and airodump-ng (and airmon-ng) to try to accomplish this, I am wondering if there are any better ideas or tools which can help me achieve this, even another language, C or Java or some other tool.

Comment: @barny I am currently in the process of trying out parsing the plain text that comes out of airodump-ng, if possible piping it to python and going through the results, i.e. line by line and detecting the MAC address by using Regex maybe, and then using that information to update the database. I am more looking for more effective ways to do this task, or if this can be considered a good way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well i hope you know about wireshark tool ,but what you want is the details about your neigboring access points and save it into a file. So lets start,

1. first you need to capture the packets floating around and filter it, right? you can do it by with help of [pcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap.3pcap.html).
2. When you capture the packets, the radiotap header will have all the information you need, with some google search you learn more about it or go through each packets in wireshark.The packets are like different layers of wrapping. i can give you a sample code of unwrapping a packet..

   ```
   static int count = 1;    /* packet counter */

   /* declare pointers to packet headers */
   const struct ieee80211_hdr  *ethernet;  /* The ethernet header [1] */
   const struct ieee80211_radiotap_header *rt;
   uint8_t *llc;

   unsigned int radioTapSize ;
   int ieee80211Size = 24;




   rt = (struct ieee80211_radiotap_header*)(packet);

   //Hex to Dec
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << std::hex << rt->it_len;
   ss >> radioTapSize;
   //std::cout << radioTapSize << std::endl;

   ethernet = (struct ieee80211_hdr*)(packet+radioTapSize);
   llc = (uint8_t *)(packet+radioTapSize+ieee80211Size);


   // LLC Value = aa:aa:03:00:00:00:08:00
   //printf("%x\n",llc[0]);
   if(llc[0] == 0xaa && llc[1] == 0xaa && llc[2] == 0x03 && llc[3] == 0x00 && llc[4] == 0x00
           && llc[5] == 0x00 && llc[6] == 0x08 && llc[7] == 0x00)
   {
           printf("\nPacket number %d:\n", count);
               count++;
           //radioTapSize = rt->it_len;
           printf("Radiotap Length : %x\n",radioTapSize);
           std::cout << "Radiotap Length : " << radioTapSize  << std::endl;
           printf("Radiotap pad : %x\n",rt->it_pad);
           printf("Radiotap present : %x\n",rt->it_present);
           printf("Radiotap version : %x\n",rt->it_version);


           int i=0;
           printf("Farme Control : %x\n",htons(ethernet->frame_control));
           printf("Duration ID : %x\n",htons(ethernet->duration_id));

           printf("Address 1: ");
           for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
           {
               if(i != 5)
                   printf(" %x:",ethernet->addr1[i]);
               else
                   printf(" %x\n",ethernet->addr1[i]);
           }


           printf("Address 2: ");
           for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
           {
               if(i != 5)
                   printf(" %x:",ethernet->addr2[i]);
               else
                   printf(" %x\n",ethernet->addr2[i]);
           }


           printf("Address 3: ");
           for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
           {
               if(i != 5)
                   printf(" %x:",ethernet->addr3[i]);
               else
                   printf(" %x\n",ethernet->addr3[i]);
           }

           printf("LLC: ");
           for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
           {
               if(i != 7)
                   printf(" %x:",llc[i]);
               else
                   printf(" %x\n",llc[i]);
           }

   }
   ```

   look, this is just an example how a packet is unwrapped.

go through pcap stuff and you can easily filter all the informations from a packet sent by your neigbors. i can give you links to some useful things 
to know more [about sending and receiving packets](http://www.wildpackets.com/resources/compendium/wireless_lan/wlan_packets).

I hope you understand it else feel free to ask.